# undeclared variable in bash (how to use variable in sub-loop)

Tags: bash, global-variables

I have this bash 4.3 script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in *.xml; do
  badid=$(xml sel -t -v "//bad/@id" "$x")
  vg=${badid%\.*}
  count=$(xml sel -t -v 'count(//bad/objdesc/desc/@id)' "$x")
  for ((i=1; i<=count; i++)); do
    id=$(xml sel -t -v "//bad/objdesc/desc[$i]/@id" "$x")
    count2=$(xml sel -t -v 'count(//bad/objdesc/desc[$i]/objtitle/objid/objcode/@code)' "$x")
    for ((j=1; j<=count2; j++)); do
        bentleynum=$(xml sel -t -v "//bad/objdesc/desc[$i]/objtitle/objid/objcode[$j]/@code" "$x")
        if [[ $bentleynum == B* ]]; then break; else continue; fi
    done
    cat<<EOF
$vg.$bentleynum $id
EOF
  done
done
```

I get this error:

```
runtime error: element call-template
Variable 'i' has not been declared.
xmlXPathCompiledEval: 1 objects left on the stack.
```

Does this have to do with the fact that I'm trying to use $i in the sub-loop? How do I use it globally (in the sub-loop)?

Comment: Use http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: didn't know about shellcheck. thanks, @Cyrus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the words of shellcheck:

```
count2=$(xml sel -t -v 'count(//bad/objdesc/desc[$i]/objtitle/objid/objcode/@code)' "$x")
                       ^-- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.
```

Your error is not a bash error, but an xmlstarlet error saying that it doesn't recognize `$i`. This makes sense because `$i` is a bash expression and not an xmlstarlet expression. If you use double quotes instead of single quotes, the `$i` will be replaced by its value, e.g. `0`, which xmlstarlet will understand.